# Swift: cannot see maps in simulator (Xcode 6 GM)

Tags: swift, grid, ios-simulator, apple-maps, xcode6gm

I'm using Xcode 6 GM, and when I'm trying to create a simple app that only shows the map, I can see only the grid (in the simulator).

Any thoughts?

Comment: To get the most out of SO community, you should show us what you have done so far.

Comment: there is no much to see, because it's very simple app that just shows the map. But here is a screenshot of my app:

http://i61.tinypic.com/2le73r.png

and I added the MapKit to the Build option.

Comment: Now I found that my maps at the mac itself doesn't work...

Comment: Yeah, it seems to work fine in XCode 6.0